# Dragging and dropping images within multiple boundries in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new with HTML5.
I have to implement such a functionality that I want images to be dropped within a canvas from outside, then there are visible boundaries within canvas and the images can be moved from one boundary to another. It is the same as in the following link,
http://custom.case-mate.com/diy?bypassLandingPage=true

As, in the site, user selects the pattern and drags images into that. Then he can drag the images between the boundaries. please give some solution for implementing such a functionality.

Here is what I have tried,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      canvas {position:relative;
        left:150%;
        border: 10px solid #9C9898;
        background-color: grey;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v3.10.0.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: "container",
          width: 300,
          height: 400,
        });

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        var redLine = new Kinetic.Line({
          points: [150, 0, 150, 400],
          stroke: "white",
          strokeWidth: 2,
        });

        var blueLine = new Kinetic.Line({
          points: [150, 0, 150, 120, 300, 120],
          stroke: "white",
          strokeWidth: 2,
        });

        var thirdLine = new Kinetic.Line({
          points: [300, 120, 150, 120, 150, 400],
          stroke: "white",
          strokeWidth: 2,
        });

        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function() {
          var image = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 50,
            y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 60,
            image: imageObj,
            width: 100,
            height: 120,

          }); 
           image.draggable(true);   
          layer.add(image);

          // add the layer to the stage
          stage.add(layer);
        };
        imageObj.src = "images/212.png";
        layer.add(redLine);
        layer.add(blueLine);
        layer.add(thirdLine);
        stage.add(layer);
};

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This [popular demo](http://html5demos.com/drag) contains all what you need if the dragged object is a link (which may contain an image). Not that in most browsers (not IE) this also works for any type of draggable object (not only links).

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried so far and describe the specific problem you're having.

Comment: I have drawn lines in the canvas, these lines can be used as boundaries for image drag. I want some idea other than what i have tried. If you have any idea of implementing the exact functionality as in the above URL.please help! I want some idea to start with.

Comment: Buty at the moment we don't know what you've tried, because you've not posted your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice tutorial on HTML5 native drag'n'drop:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Basically you can declare an item as draggable in HTML5 with the draggable attribute

```
<div class="draggable" draggable="true">A</div>
<div class="draggable" draggable="true">B</div>
```

...and then use Javascript to handle some events like:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
[].forEach.call(items, function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('dragstart', function(){ /*handle drag start*/ }, false);
  item.addEventListener('dragenter', function(){ /*handle drag enter*/ }, false)
  item.addEventListener('dragover',  function(){ /*handle drag over*/ }, false);
  item.addEventListener('dragleave', function(){ /*handle drag leave*/ }, false);
  item.addEventListener('drop',      function(){ /*handle drop*/ }, false);
  item.addEventListener('dragend',   function(){ /*handle drag end*/ }, false);
});
```

Comment: Well I need to implement the same functionality as in the above given URL. When user selects a pattern, It appears in the specified area. As, you can see the pattern contains divisions for dragging and dropping images. And after adjusting the images within these boundaries, I have to save the specified area as a single image(like print screen). So, should i make a big div and on selection, make new small divs within big div using javascript with the specified pattern!